# display count on same field based on different criteria from same table

Tags: sql, pivot

Say my table has only 2 fields: `Id` and `color`.

```
id  color
----------
1   Green
2   Red
3   Yellow
```

I want the count to be displayed in a row not in a column.

```
  SELECT COUNT(color), color
    FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY color
```

This gives me:

```
count   color
--------------
10      Green
20      Red
15      Yellow
```

I need it to be displayed as:

```
Green  Red  Yellow
-------------------
10     20   15
```

Comment: Knowing the database would help, but the PIVOT tag has info how to do this (along with existing questions that cover this).

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE Color WHEN 'Green'  THEN 1 END) AS Green,
  COUNT(CASE Color WHEN 'Red'    THEN 1 END) AS Red,
  COUNT(CASE Color WHEN 'Yellow' THEN 1 END) AS Yellow
FROM MYTABLE
```

You don't need grouping here. Basically, every `COUNT` passes all the rows but *counts* only those where `Color` matches a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

```
select (select COUNT(color) from MyTable where color='Green') as 'Green', 
       (select COUNT(color) from MyTable where color='Red') as 'Red'. 
       (select COUNT(color) from MyTable where color='Yellow') as 'Yellow'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this (**in MySQL only**) is:

```
SELECT SUM(color = 'Green')  AS "Green"
     , SUM(color = 'Red')    AS "Red"
     , SUM(color = 'Yellow') AS "Yellow"
FROM MyTable ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link http://blog.programmingsolution.net/sql-server-2008/sql-server-pivot-converting-rows-to-columns-with-dynamic-query/

but if you do somthing like this

```
 select [ID],[COLOUR] from

 ( SELECT [ID],[COLOUR] FROM [dbo].[table] ) as S

 Pivot ( COUNT([COLOUR])

 FOR COLOUR IN ([YELLOW],[RED],[GREEN])

 ) as P
```